# Perl using File::Spec to remove .. and . from path

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm using [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) on a Unix system to get the absolute path of a file:

```
use File::Spec::Functions qw(:ALL);
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $file = "../../this/is/a/test";

say rel2abs($file);
```

This prints out `/directory/to/program/../../this/is/a/test`. I'd like it to print out `/directory/this/is/a/test`.

I saw the `no_upwards` method, and here's the description:

```
Given a list of file names, strip out those that refer to a parent directory.
(Does not strip symlinks, only '.', '..', and equivalents.)

     @paths = File::Spec->no_upwards( @paths );
```

However, this didn't seem to work. Instead, I looked at the code in the File::Spec module and found this:

```
sub no_upwards {
    my $self = shift;
    return grep(!/^\.{1,2}\z/s, @_);
}
```

So, what does this method do, and how do I get it to work?

If I'm reading this right, this takes a list of directories, and then removes all those directories that are `.` or `..`. (According to Perldoc `\z` means *match only at the end of a string*).

Is there a ***platform independent*** way of collapsing these special directories? What is `no_upwards` suppose to do, and how do you use it? I tried:

```
 say no_upwards(rel2abs($file));
```

Is there another method I should be using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the documentation for [canonpath](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html#canonpath) in [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html), it says:

> ### METHODS
>
> #### canonpath
>
> No physical check on the filesystem, but a logical cleanup of a path.
>
> ```
> $cpath = File::Spec->canonpath( $path ) ;
> ```
>
> Note that this does *not* collapse `x/../y` sections into `y`.  This is
>   by design.  If `/foo` on your system is a symlink to `/bar/baz`, then
>   `/foo/../quux` is actually `/bar/quux`, not `/quux` as a naive `../`-removal
>   would give you.  If you want to do this kind of processing, you
>   probably want [Cwd](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html)'s [realpath()](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html#abs_path-and-friends) function to actually traverse the
>   filesystem cleaning up paths like this.

So I'd look into using [Cwd](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html)'s [realpath()](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html#abs_path-and-friends) function like it says.

Comment: Thanks. I first tried it in my program and it printed nothing. Apparently, you have to have the name of a _real_ file. Since working on a rewrite of File::Find, that's not really a problem. I just hope it works on Perl systems besides Win/Mac/Unix/Linux.

Comment: I just know the quirks of Stack Overflow's [variant of Markdown](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/).

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question

> So, what does this method do, and how do I get it to work?

when you `ls -a` on your terminal, it will give you something like 
`. .. some_folder some_file.txt another_file.txt`

`no_upwards()` simply removes the `.` and `..` and return the list 
`some_folder some_file.txt another_file.txt`

Comment: It certainly doesn't do what I want in this particular instance. However, there is a place in my program where I read in a directory and then remove `.` and `..`, so I'll use it there. It pretty much does what I thought, but your explanation clarified why. I wish the documentation was a bit clearer.